# import resources together with class python

Tags: python, package

I have a class called MicroServicesRCA. This class is inside a project (/Users/alvarobrandon/PycharmProjects/microservices-rca) that has some json resources in a directory of the project (/Users/alvarobrandon/PycharmProjects/microservices-rca/workflows). So inside the class methods I just use the relative path to import the file

```
with open('workflows/example.json') as infile:
```

To be able to import the class from some other project, I include the microservices-rca directory in the sys.path but when I try to execute one of the class functions it obviously gives me an IOError since I used relative paths:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'workflows/example.json'
```

I know that the following two lines in the init.py, will extend the path to include the files when importing microservices-rca package

```
from pkgutil import extend_path
__path__ = extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

My question. Is there anyway to include the files in workflows directory by just importing the class?. Basically I want to include this json files in the path by just doing something like:

```
from microservices_rca import MicroServicesRCA
```

instead of

```
import microservices_rca
```

Comment: I'm guessing the quotes missing in your `open` statement are just a copy issue from your program?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that